# Check if array contains property id with Linq / C#

Tags: c#

currently I loop through arrays and check if any objects contain a specific id. These objects have a `Id` property.

```
public class MyObj
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

So when checking the locked state I go for this code

```
bool IsUnlocked(int targetId) {
 bool isUnlocked = false;

 for (int i = 0; i < myObjs.Length; i++) // loop trough the objects
 {
  MyObj current = myObjs[i];

  if (current.Id == targetId) // a match
  {
   isUnlocked = true;
   break;
  }
 }

 return isUnlocked;
}
```

I think this can be done smarter with Linq. I tried

```
bool isUnlocked = myObjs.Contains(current => current.Id == targetId);
```

but this is a wrong syntax. Do I have to setup something like

```
myObjs.First(current => current.Id == targetId);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Contains` doesn't take a delegate type so passing the behaviour of `current => current.Id == targetId` into it would not compile.

As for `myObjs.First(current => current.Id == targetId);`, this will return the first object that satisfies the provided predicate as opposed to returning a `bool` indicated if there is any item that satisfies the provided predicate or not.

The solution is to use the `Any` extension method.

```
bool isUnlocked = myObjs.Any(current => current.Id == targetId);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a dedicated method in the `Array` class - [Array.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Array_Exists__1___0___System_Predicate___0__):

```
 isUnlocked = Array.Exists(myObjs, elem => elem.Id == targetId);
```